# Some text titles are missing in FL Studio (through wine inside Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: wine, snap, fonts

I've tried installing FL Studio `wine flstudio_win64_21.2.2.3914.exe` and through `snap sudo snap install flstudio --candidate`. Both methods install the program itself, but some textual comments below the buttons are missing, as shown below (highlighted with red):

[image]

I read that this is due to some fonts missing. What are these fonts and how should I add them? When I try to add some some fonts with winetricks it says:

[image]

And when I try to kill all wine processes (using snap install with `wine -k`) I get the following error:

[image]

How should I fix this in case of direct wine or snap installation. Alternative installation methods are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, following steps from [here](https://forum.image-line.com/viewtopic.php?t=270394).

In short - install latest wine and winetricks from developers, not from repository and run

`./winetricks corefonts` to install major fonts.

All text captions are now present:

[image]